# Generalizing the damped harmonic oscillator equation to 3D

Tags: friction, harmonic-oscillator

I am way out of my depth here so bear with me. I haven't done any physics in a few years so my memory is rusty.

The equation for a damped harmonic oscillator is:

$$x(t) = A\exp(-bt/2m)\cos(ω*t + \phi)$$

After some simplification, as I am not really interested by all the constants, I arrived at:

$$x(t) = A\exp(-t)\sin(2\pi t + \phi)$$

Now as far as I can understand, this equation is in 2D, since you have one parameter and one function. Now I want to generalize it for 3D so I can animate it in Mathematica. What I have in mind is a ripple like effect that emanates from the center. Like it happens when a raindrop hits the water surface. Again, this may be wrong, but it seems any molecule of water acts like a damped harmonic oscillator to me, so it makes sense to try to model that with the 3D equivalent of the 2D equation.

So what I want to do is generalize the equation but for 3D. I have a feeling I will also need to use polar coordinates (just intuition, not sure if necessary, because all waves emanating from the center are in phase at the same radius if that makes sense).

How can this equation be generalized to 3D?

So in the end, the equation should look like this:

$p(x, y)$ = something and t needs to be in there somewhere as well, and I will compute p(x, y) for every t in [0, 2] let's say to get an animation.

**What I tried so far**

I remember something from school where the equation of a circle is x^2 + y^2 = 0. I don't know why, but I tried doing something like this:

$$p(x,y) = x^2 A\exp(-t)\sin(2\pi t + \phi) + y^2 A\exp(-t)\sin(2\pi t + \phi)$$

I don't have any rationale for it, it just seemed like the right idea but it doesn't seem to have worked.

Comment: Please use MathJax: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: I did though. You can see it is formatted properly

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry about that. I guess I am seeing a bunch of $*$ symbols that are not common in Mathjax. You usually don't explicitly write multiplication as $*$ since it looks quite weird inside math markup. I'll make an edit to clean it up.

Comment: (I also replaced "exp" with "\exp," "cos" with "\cos," and "sin" with "\sin," which makes the rendering look nicer)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "dimensions." If by 3D you mean *existing in a three-dimensional spatial world*, then the vanilla $x(t)=x_0 e^{-bt/2m}\cos(\omega t+\varphi)$ oscillator is already "3D." Think of a mass oscillating on a damped spring - it exists in three dimensions, it just only moves in one direction.

If you want to model a disturbance that propagates in *all directions,* you could use spherical coordinates (or polar coordinates):
$$A(r,t)=\frac{A_0}{r}e^{i (kr-\omega t)}.$$
This equation models, for example, the field strength of light emanating from a point source passing through a medium with nonzero [attenuation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_constant#Attenuation_constant) (it does not, however, model water waves since water particles oscillate circularly, and thus don't undergo harmonic motion at all).